# How must I use the Java API to facilitate failover?

Tags: java, api, riak

I am trying to use Riak from my java app in such a way that if one of the machines in the cluster goes down, it will just start using the other machines. I managed to do this using Corrugated Iron drivers in C# but can't seem to make it work in java.

I've made sure that I'm specifying more than one Riak machine in the PBClusterConfig, ie that the client 'knows about' all of the machines in the cluster.

I set up the `PBClusterConfig` like this:

```
BClusterConfig config = new PBClusterConfig(maxConnections);
for(RiakServerConfig server : servers) {
    PBClientConfig.Builder builder = new PBClientConfig.Builder();
    PBClientConfig serverConfig = builder
        .withHost(server.getHostname())
        .withPort(server.getPort())
        .build();

    config.addClient(serverConfig);
}
```

Then my actual operations (only read and write) looks like this:

```
client
    .createBucket(bucket)
    .withRetrier(DefaultRetrier.attempts(3))
    .execute()
    .store(key, value)
    .withRetrier(DefaultRetrier.attempts(3))
    .execute();
```

When the riak cluster is fine this code works, but when one of the machines goes down I get the following error after a few seconds: `com.basho.riak.client.RiakRetryFailedException: com.basho.riak.pbc.AcquireConnectionTimeoutException: timeout acquiring connection permit from pool`.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is still an [outstanding issue regarding how the cluster client handles node failures](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/issues/147). One workaround I have seen recommended on the riak mailing list is to install e.g. [HAProxy on the application server](http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2011-March/003461.html) and have this handle fail-overs.